# Provided id of the wrong type hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, type-mismatch

I am getting error:

org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class BEntity. Expected: class BEntity, got class AEntity

```
public class BEntity implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NUM")
    private String num;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INIT")
    private String init;

    @Column(name = "V_CNT")
    private Integer vcnt;

   //{{{some column omitted}}}//
}

public class AEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NUM")
    private String num;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INIT")
    private String init;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="NUM", referencedColumnName="NUM"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="INIT", referencedColumnName="INIT")
    })
    private BEntity bEntity;
}
```

***HQL query:***

```
String queryString = "FROM AEntity AS A " +
                     "LEFT JOIN A.bEntityAS B " +
                     "WHERE A.INIT||A.NUM IN (:carList) AND A.INIT IN (:initList) AND A.NUM IN (:numberList) " + 
                     "AND B.TRUK_AXL_CNT > 0";
```

***Hibernate gen-code***

```
select aentity0_.NUMBER as NUMBER4_0_, aentity0_.INITIAL as INITIAL4_0_, bentity_p1_.NUMBER as NUMBER5_1_, bentity_p1_.INITIAL as INITIAL5_1_, aentity0_.V_CNT as VCNT3_4_0_, aentity0_.EIN as EIN4_0_, aentity0_.TYP as TYP5_4_0_, aentity0_.TRUK_CNT as TRUK6_4_0_, bentity_p1_.TRUK_AXL_CNT as TRUK3_5_1_ from USR.aentity aentity0_ left outer join USR.bentity_PRIMARY bentity_p1_ on aentity0_.NUMBER=bentity_p1_.NUMBER and aentity0_.INITIAL=bentity_p1_.INITIAL 
where (aentity0_.INITIAL||aentity0_.NUMBER in (?,?,?)) 
and (aentity0_.INITIAL in (?,?,?)) 
and (aentity0_.NUMBER in (?, ?, ?))
and bentity_p1_.TRUK_AXL_CNT>0
```

When I run the code in SQL Explorer it works only running it in code cause the issue...

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using? Are you using core, or with JPA? Tested here with JPA+Hibernate 4.1.3 and it went fine (no error). Are you sure that the error is on the select, or in another part of the code?

Comment: was using hibernate 4.1.2 core

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like this is a defect in hibernate version 3.2.6 which is still not resolved. Came across this [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3993).

Having multiple `@Id` is supported by Hibernate but seems it fails under one to one mapping, suggested way of resolving this is to use single CompositeKey, which means you create a PK class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class PKClass implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "NUM")
    private String num;

    @Column(name = "INIT")
    private String init;

    //gettter setter here

}
```

then in your Entity use this as the ID

```
public class BEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private PKClass pkClass = null;

    @Column(name = "V_CNT")
    private Integer vcnt;

   //{{{some column omitted}}}//
}

public class AEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private PKClass pkClass = null;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="NUM", referencedColumnName="NUM"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="INIT", referencedColumnName="INIT")
    })
    private BEntity bEntity;
}
```

Comment: Have you really tried your solution? I just get "com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML" but the OneToOne relationship is bi-directional in my case. Why do you use @Id instead of @EmbeddedId?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue. I had two separate PK classes that had the same fields. So I removed one PK and used only one in the owner and child entity. This solved the problem.

Comment: Vote up! Had the same error and was because of this. Even if the classes for pk were notated @Embeddable, there were two classes having the same fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

**Started situation**

*Primary key on master table*

```
        <composite-id name="id" class="model.E1Id">
        <key-property name="taxpayerId" type="int">
            <column name="TaxpayerID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="year" type="int">
            <column name="Year" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
```

*Primary key on detail table*

```
 <composite-id name="id" class="model.E1dataFromTaxPayerFolderId">
        <key-property name="tid" type="int">
            <column name="tID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="year" type="int">
            <column name="Year" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
```

**After repair**
I change the class of detail table composite-id and i set the class of primary table like this:

```
        <composite-id name="id" class="model.E1Id">
        <key-property name="tid" type="int">
                            <column name="tID" />
                    </key-property>
        <key-property name="year" type="int">
            <column name="Year" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
```

After that is necessary (if you have different names) to add in your primarykey class (in my case E1Id) the property tid (with getter and setter methods)